# Deployment of symfony project?

Tags: symfony, deployment, doctrine

After uploading my symfony2 project to the server, I try to reload :
http://my_website.com/web/app_dev.php and it show me this error :

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry'
>   not found in /my_path/app/autoload.php on line 11

Comment: Did you installed the vendors with `composer install`?

Comment: Also make sure you use `app.php` on production environments.

Comment: as well make sure to execute all required app/console commans with --env=prod (or --no-dev, whatever guarantees that you execute them not for dev stage).

Comment: i will try these solutions ,

Comment: it work fine , i have installed vendors , tank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A missing class can indicate that the dependencies are missing. You have to install them with Composer:

```
composer install
```

And you can adjust options:

- `--prefer-dist`: download zip files instead of using git repositories
- `-vvv --profile`: display more verbose output

Which gives:

```
composer install --prefer-dist -vvv --profile
```